# What is my mother's family name on a UK visa application form?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

This question is inspired by the other names question. What is the mother's family name?

In the guidance it says:

> 4.7 Mother’s family name:
>   This should be the name by which your mother’s family is known.

https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/589168/VAF1-guidance.pdf

I've always thought this meant my mother's maiden surname.

Comment: That's what it *does* mean. What were you thinking it meant?

Comment: @Greg Hewgill I just checked the Visa4UK website and it wants me to enter my mother's name as it appears in her passport.

Comment: Perhaps we can invite @Gayot Fow to answer this one.

Comment: I would assume it means mother's surname, if she has one. it's phrased to be inclusive of cultures which don't have a 'surname', or where the family name isn't the last name.

Comment: @DJClayworth the wording seems to imply that "your mother's family" is not the same as your own family. When I visit my mother's family, I mean my maternal grandparents, uncles and aunts. They have the same question for "your father's family" but since he shares his surname with his family's it's not confusing. In any case, it makes much more sense to ask about my mother's current legal name than her birth name. But the ambiguous wording creates confusion.

Comment: Yes I meant of course "mother's maiden surname".

Comment: @greatone it doesn't make sense to ask your mother's current last name if the purpose of the question is to identify you. Your mother's current last name is a changeable thing, like your address. Your mother's surname at the moment she was born will not change over time. In theory it could also be used for genealogical research although I don't think that's why the visa people ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be tautological but the guidance couldn't be any more explicit:

> 4.7 Mother’s family name
>
> This should be **the name by which your mother’s family is known.**

This means that you're essentially asked to provide the current surname of your mother's father. This would also be your mother's maiden name, unless her family decided to change their last name at some point after her birth.

Comment: This strikes me as a bureaucrat trying to define "mother's maiden name" in a way that works when family names aren't always last names, and when women don't always change their names on marriage, or even get married. Anyone from a culture that has the concept of "mother's maiden name" should just put that. People from other cultures may have to work a little harder to figure out what name to supply.

Comment: The Visa4UK website for the same application asks me to enter mother's family name as shown in her passport. Why are they asking for two different names on what is essentially the same form?

Comment: @greatone your mother's family name is presumably different from the one she was born with, assuming she took her husband's name. So they're not the same.

Comment: @JonathanReez You're contradicting your answer. Is the mother's family name her father's surname or her husband's surname (as in her passport)? The VISA4UK website explicitly asks for the passport name. The VAF1 guidance says "This should be the name by which your mother’s family is known." Both forms are for visitor visa applications.

Comment: @greatone I was referring to the family name shown in her passport

Comment: @JonathanReez That's obvious. Why are two versions of essentially the same form asking for different family names?

Comment: @greatone because they're not the same! One is your mother's *current* name as of her latest passport. The other is her maiden last name.